# ANT classpath inside Spring Boot runnable jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, ant

I am migrating a project from Spring to Springboot. Let's call it **Project X**. Inside it, I am having a class named **ClassA**. I am also using Apache ANT (we cannot migrate to Maven now). I have managed to create a runnable jar file with ANT using Spring Boot AntLib Module named **projectX.jar**.

My problem is now **Project Y** - a project which has a compile dependency of **Project X**. When I try to compile **Project Y** with ANT, I have:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
<pathelement path="D:\ProjectX\projectX.jar"/>
</path>
```

Since I have migrated to SpringBoot, the structure of **projectX.jar** has changed a little bit. Now my classes are under *BOOT-INF/classes* inside **projectX.jar** (instead of directly in the root path of **projectX.jar**). Because of this, **Project Y** is no longer finding **classA**.

Error is:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import myPackage.classA;
```

Is there any way to reference those classes by specifying their location inside the jar?
What I have tried is:

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement path="D:\ProjectX\projectX.jar\BOOT-INF\classes"/> 
</path>
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
I was also thinking about unpacking those classes from **ProjectX** to disk, reference them from there on **ProjectY** and then delete them at the end, but this looks like a dirtly solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated.